# Как удалить ключ и значение в словаре Python если значение ключа None

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Как удалить ключ и значение если они равны None

```
a = {'a': None, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': None, 'e': 3}
```

Comment: `{key: value for key, value in a.items() if value is not None}`

Answer (score 0):

Еще как вариант можно использовать [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter).

```
a = {'a': None, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': None, 'e': 3}
filtered = dict(filter(lambda x: x[1] is not None, a.items()))
print(filtered)
```

> {'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'e': 3}